# Material alpha/tga textures?

Tags: texturing, uv, image, transparency

I'm sorry about the title being vague, I wouldn't say I'm a noob in Blender but sometimes it's hard to find the right words to describe issues when you've not explored the software completely.
Either way, I'm still learning about materials & textures, and I've downloaded this model of sick sexy cowboy man Arthur Morgan. The issue I'm having is that objects that should accommodate transparency (like his eyebrows and hair) show up opaque with a black background; when the pictures used in image texture have an alpha channel preventing that.
Here's a picture of the issue as well as the nodes setting on the material, and a picture of all of the kind of material images included in the model's folder. I've only used the normal map and the image texture so far, the others I honestly still don't know what they're for lmaooooo[image]

tysm!!!

Comment: try connecting the alpha from the image to the alpha of your princial bsdf

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Eevee? If so, it may be because your material needs to be set up to allow alpha transparency

Go to the material tab (in the properties window, by default to the right, Behind where your textures are in the screenshot) and, with the material in question selected, scroll down until you get to the Options panel.

Underneath Options you should see a drop down menu for Blend Mode. Change this to Alpha Clip or Alpha Blend (which ever works best for your material at the time).

Your character may be made out of several objects with several materials, all of which will need this adjustment, so don’t get confused if, by fixing the alpha on the eyebrows, the hair still looks off for example.